# Execute a legacy stored procedure with Django

Tags: django

I'm writing a django application on top of a legacy database. There is a batch input process which I'd like to control via the django app.

I have a template and class based view (a ListView) to display the contents of the batch input table, add new items, edit existing items etc. and that works fine.

I'm now wondering how best to process the batch. The database has a stored procedure which I need to execute. I can add a button to the template, but I'm unsure where to place the 'execution' code and how best to return the messages from the stored procedure.

Anybody got any guidance or thoughts that might point me in the right direction?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805393/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-stored-procedures-in-djangos-orm) may offer some help. A comment on one of the answers suggests Django's design expects you just to use SQL for things like this. IMO that's probably the right approach.

Comment: I've created a manager class, added a method to call the stored procedure and made that the manager for the model. Just got to work out how to call the manager method now!