# How to use stored procedure or function created in mysql in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, rdbms

As I am learning django and MySql , I am creating a web page and want to use PlSql queries like triggers and procedure in my website using django. I have made connection of MySql and django. Can anyone help me how to proceed further.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/805393/9456405)

Answer (score 0):

You can run as SQL query like:

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT add(1,2);")
    resp= cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!