# Query database in django using model procedure

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have created model with procedure that subtract two dates from fields in model returning days difference between them, for example:

```
class Example:
    earlierDate=models.DateField()
    laterDate=models.DateField()

    def day_diff(self):
        return (laterDate-earlierDate).days
```

Is it possible to query database including day_diff procedure ?

in_views_query=Example.objects.filter(day_diff__gte=30)

When i use this kind o query it shows me that there is no field 'day_diff'

Regards

Comment: check this out, let me know if that helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/805393/9102309

Comment: @Vedprakash Upraity actually it is not what i'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ExpressionWrapper` to make this happen

```
from django.db.models import DateField, ExpressionWrapper, F

Example.objects.annotate(day_diff=ExpressionWrapper(
                F('laterDate') - F('earlierDate'), output_field=models.DateField()
))
```

Django also has a similar example in docs. check it out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations